# Will installing 2 conda on one computer mess up anything?

Tags: python, anaconda, arcgis, conda

Currently I have installed a software called ArcGIS Pro 2.1 in **C:\Program Files** and it comes with a conda that is the only python I have on this computer. Now I need python for other projects and I don't want to go through IT department every time I need to install some python packages because I don't have the admin right.

Will installing another conda in a folder that I have right to edit mess up anything of the ArcGIS conda?

Or can I use the ArcGIS conda to create another python environment outside **C:\Program Files** in a folder I have right to edit?[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for virtual environments. They're the standard solution to your problem. How they interact (or don't) with Anaconda is something I don't know, though, so you'll need to look into it. But virtual environments allow installing standard Python packages from PyPI separately from the global install.

Comment: OP is using conda for virtual environment creation. Conda technically removes the need for virtualenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to leverage the existing conda. You just need to make sure you always use the `--prefix` command to actually write the environment folder into a directory you can write to.

[Check out the conda-create help docs. Look at the --prefix option](https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-create.html)

-- Edit -- 
There's actually an existing thread discussion about it. Check out this other SO link [how to specify new environment location for conda create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926940/how-to-specify-new-environment-location-for-conda-create)

Comment: I followed the post and created a new environment outside the Program Files. But how can I activate jupyter notebook for that environment? it said "'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: After you create your conda environment outside of Program Files... 1) Make sure you activate the env (folder location). 2) Since you did a fresh env (i.e you didn't copy another env)... you have to re-install your libraries. So just do `conda install jupyter`