# Need the full path when activating Conda environment?

Tags: python

I'm new to the Conda environment and I was trying to create an environment by `conda create -n chip python=2.7`, and then `source activate chip` to activate the environment, but then I got the error message:

```
Could not find conda environment: chip
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
```

And `conda info --envs` returned me:

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/yin/miniconda3
                         /anaconda3
                         /anaconda3/envs/chip
```

I tried `source activate /anaconda3/envs/chip` and it worked.
So can I add a name to my new environment (e.g. chip) so that I can activate it without typing the full path?
Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How many conda installations do you have and how did you create the `chip` environment?  Based on your output the path for the `conda` executable is pointing to the conda installation in `/Users/yin/miniconda3` and it may not know about environments installed in other directory trees.

When you create a conda environment using `conda create -n chip` it should be created in the `envs` sub-directory of where your conda distribution is installed, i.e., `/Users/yin/miniconda3/envs/chip`.  Then you can refer to the environment by its name, i.e., `source activate chip`.

When you create a conda environment using `conda create -p the_env_path` it will be created in `the_env_path` and you will have to refer to it by its path when using `activate`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I used `conda create -n chip` but I might type something differently by accident. I tried `conda create -n chip` again to create a new environment and I could access it without typing the full path. So now can I move the `chip` to `/Users/yin/miniconda3/envs/chip` or do anything else to solve this problem?

Comment: I ended up creating a new environment and moving everything into that environment and it worked.

Comment: @Yin Good to hear.  If you have found this response helpful please mark as "accepted answer".

Answer (score 1):

Rather than moving the environment around (which can cause issues), a better solution is to add the envs folder to the `envs_dirs` key-value list in `.condarc`, e.g.:

```
ssl_verify: true
channels:
  - defaults
envs_dirs:
  - C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda3\envs
  - D:\envs
```

Then all the environments will be available by their aliases in addition to their full paths. Answer shamelessly stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56903431/1284670.