# How to use a custome env in a SageMaker Notebook Job?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr

I have created a custom env and deployed an image to ECR. The image has been added to the images in Sagemaker and I am able to use it in Sagemaker notebooks. However, when launching a notebook job, I get `Exception during processing notebook: No such kernel named conda-env-customenv-py`. Is there an additional policy or setup required to use it in jobs?

I do not want to use lifecycle configurations in order to minimize the start time.

Answer (score 0):

Before edit:

Instead of deploying image on ECR , you can specify libraries and create environment via lifecycle configuration , as soon as you open your sagemaker notebook instance , your desired env populates

After edit:

You can use sagemaker studio notebook and attach ecr image to the studio UI here is the [reference](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/bringing-your-own-custom-container-image-to-amazon-sagemaker-studio-notebooks/)

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to do that in a notebook job to avoid the time required to install the packages.

Answer (score 0):

Since the docker images behind the notebooks change frequently, one way is to create an env inside the only persistent directory, `Sagemaker`, and have jupyter recognise it for it to show up in the list of kernels to be chosen in the list of available kernels.

First, create a venv inside `Sagemaker` directory, that the notebook env opens(or "boots") to, activate it to install `ipykernel` and register it in the list of kernels:

```
$ pip install ipykernel
$ python -m ipykernel install --user --name="<kernel name>" --display-name="<My Official Kernel Name>"
```

Then verify it in the list of available kernels:

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  test       /Sagemaker/myname/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/test
  python3    /Sagemaker/myname/.local/share/virtualenvs/mydirectory-44neAqC_/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

Now, restart the notebook venv and you should find your new venv in the list of kernels to choose to run the notebook.

[source for above](https://sesync-ci.github.io/faq/python-virtual-env.html).

find more help in [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926940/how-to-specify-new-environment-location-for-conda-create).

After every restart, though your venv resides in the `Sagemaker` directory, it's registration in the list of kernels won't. So, you can write a "Lifecycle configuration" that runs *before* your notebook instance is started on the machine to automatically register your venv every time.